# Finding the distribution for the sum of two identical distributed random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Problem:

Let $X$ and  $Y$ be identically distributed independent random variable with
the density function
$$ f(y)  = \begin{cases}
e^{-t} & t \geq 0 \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} $$

Answer:

Let $Z = X  + Y$. Now we want to find a density function for $Z$ by using the convoluation. Let $g(u)$ be the density function for $Z$.
\begin{align*}
g(u) &= \int_0^{ \infty }f(v)f(u-v) \,\,  dv \\
g(u) &= \int_0^{ \infty } e^{-v} e^{-(u-v)} \,\,  dv \\
g(u) &= \int_0^{ \infty } e^{-v} e^{-u + v} \,\,  dv \\
g(u) &= \int_0^{ \infty } e^{-u} \,\,  dv \\
g(u) &= \int_0^{ \infty } e^{-u}v \bigg|_{v=0}^{v=\infty} \\
g(u) &= 0 - e^{-u} \\
g(u) &= - e^{-u}
\end{align*}
However, the book gets:
$$ g(u)  = \begin{cases}
 ue^{-u} & u \geq 0 \\
 0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases} $$
Where did I go wrong?

Comment: *Hint*: What is the value of $f(u-v)$ when $u-v<0$?  It is not $e^{-(u-v)}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you had retained the restriction on the support of $X$ and $Y$, you would not have been led astray.  That is, $$f(t) = e^{-t}$$ **only when** $t \ge 0$.  Otherwise, it is zero.  So when you write

$$g(u) = \int_{v=0}^\infty f(v)f(u-v) \, dv,$$

whenever $v > u$, then $f(u-v) = 0$.  So the upper limit of integration should be

$$\begin{align}
g(u) &= \int_{v=0}^{\color{red}{u}} f(v)f(u-v) \, dv \\
&= \int_{v=0}^u e^{-v} e^{-(u-v)} \, dv \\
&= \int_{v=0}^u e^{-u} \, dv \\
&= ue^{-u}.
\end{align}$$
And the restriction on $u$ is that $u \ge 0$, since if $u < 0$, then the integral is taken over an interval that is negative.